# Multiscreen and workspace issue

Tags: macos, workspace

I'm having a recurrent issue with my multiscreen setup with Mac. I have a mac book pro with 10.13.4 sierra OS.

About my issue, I two additional screens connected through HDMI with two USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter.

I usually have a second workspace on my middle screen. But when I lock my computer, my two workspaces move to the laptop screen and I can only move one to the middle screen. The other one is stuck on the laptop screen and I have to move all its application manually.

So:

- Is there a way to move all the workspaces from a screen if I create a
  new workspace on the said screen?
- Is there a way to prevent the
  workspaces in my middle screen to move to my laptop screen?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I''d love to say, 'yes you can fix this with x,y,z'. Unfortunately, it's a common issue with external screens & sleeping computers. It's exacerbated if the 2 screens in question are identical - the computer often cannot tell which is which.

Comment: Arf, I almost hate that I cannot move all the workspace from one screen to another. I can only move one, the other seems to be considered as the main workspace, and therefore cannot be moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create an extra workspace to leave on the primary monitor

I don't have a Mac with me at the moment to test this on, but seeing as your issue seems to be caused by the fact that you apparently must leave one workspace on the primary monitory, I think this'll work:

If you create a third workspace and leave it on the laptop's built-in monitor, the OS can treat that as the 'main' workspace, and you should be able to move the other 2 to the secondary monitor.

Comment: Apple should really fix this. It is pretty easy to just pick another workspace as the main one if I really want to move the main one.